# Add users to a certain AD group depending on their Department

Tags: powershell

I want to automatically add users from a specific Department to a specific AD Security Group.

For example, add all users with the AD Department attribute `Sales`, `Reception` or `Finance` to the Security Group called `APP Group`.

I've managed to come up with the code beneath which only **displays** the users regarding the specific Departments.

Can someone explain me how to expand this code so the Users are added to the security group?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties department | 
    Where-Object {$_.department -Like "Sales" -or $_.department -Like "Reception" -or $_.department -Like "Finance"} | 
        Select sAMAccountName, department
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the desired users and use this as input for [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) like this:

```
$UserList = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties department | 
    Where-Object {$_.department -Like "Sales" -or $_.department -Like "Reception" -or $_.department -Like "Finance"} | 
        Select sAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'APP Group' -Members $UserList
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your actual Filter requirements in `Get-ADUser -Filter` is much faster than piping everything to `Where-Object` and having it sort through *all the users in your domain*.

You can then use the pipeline to add the users to the group with [`Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adprincipalgroupmembership) .

```
$filter = 'Department -eq "Sales" -Or Department -eq "Reception" -Or Department -eq "Finance"'
Get-ADUser -Filter $filter | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'APP Group'
```

I've put the filter in variable for readability, but it could be a one-liner:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -eq "Sales" -Or Department -eq "Reception" -Or Department -eq "Finance"' | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'APP Group'
```

---

**EDIT:**

I can't test as working remotely, but you should just be able to filter out the users in the group already using `memberof`:

```
$ADGroup = 'APP Group'
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -eq "Sales" -Or Department -eq "Reception" -Or Department -eq "Finance"' | 
    Where-Object {!($_.memberof -like $ADGroup)} |
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $ADGroup
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The code works unless there is a user already member of the group. Then it will display a warning and stop the command. I've tried to expand the code to SilentlyContinue but that doesn't work. Is there any way to skip duplicates?